# Where can I find tutorials about correcting gate errors in the quantum circuit?

Tags: error-correction

I just have a question about where can I find tutorials/examples about correcting gate errors (amplitude errors and phase errors) in a quantum circuit? Are there any resources I can learn from? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean correcting them through quantum control (meaning improving your gates) or through circuits (meaning error correction)?

Comment: I'm wondering to correct them through circuits, but I think both would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For quantum circuits:

So the main answer is that far-term quantum computers will implement Quantum Error Correction, where each logical qubit is composed out of a number of physical qubits and the information is stored in a complex entangled state. Errors on these physical qubits can be caught and corrected, and these error correction steps will occur between each logical gate.

In terms of NISQ/smaller algorithms, it depends on the type of error your system has. [This](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.121.250502)  is a paper our group wrote on correcting overrotation type errors in QEC circuits. There is also other work on other types of errors. In general Flag qubit schemes can catch errors, although they generally don't give enough information to correct the error fully.

For quantum control:
This really depends on the architecture you're considering, but most gates have their physical implementations set up to be robust to some types of noise in order to improve fidelity. For example [SK1](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.70.052318) and [BB1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.4719.pdf) are two composite pulse techniques that allow gates to be less noisy by making them robust to overrotation errors.